# Error: file ended while scanning use of \@writefile

Tags: compiling

Everytime I make an error in the coding, the terminal tells me where it is when I compile it. But, after correcting it and running it again, this appears:

[image]

And I have to erase the .log and .aux files to make it work again.

This is my preamble:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,oneside,DIV=10]{book}


    \title{Interacciones fuertes}
    \date{\today}
    \author{-}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %to include more or less information in the table of contents
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} %para evitar cortes de palabras debido a falta de espacio en la línea
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{color, xcolor, soulutf8} %to highlight with \hl{}
    \usepackage{datetime}
    \usepackage{cancel}
    \usepackage{slashed} 
    \usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %para escribir cosas en cajitas
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage{graphicx} %necessary for images
    \usepackage{subcaption} %necessary for images
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[font={small}]{caption} %to make the text in captions of images smaller
    \numberwithin{equation}{section} %to number the equations by sections
    \usepackage{enumerate} %to make lists with letters
    \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
    \usepackage[    protrusion=true,
        expansion=true,
        final,
        babel
            ]{microtype} %para arreglar que las palabras se salgan del margen de la derecha
    \usepackage{hyperref} %as a rule-of-thumb, this package should be the last one you load
        \hypersetup{
            bookmarksnumbered, %para poner el numerito en el indice del pdf
            breaklinks=false,
            linktocpage=false,
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            citecolor=black,
            urlcolor=blue,
            menucolor=black}

        \textheight 21.8cm
           \textwidth 16.5cm
        \topmargin -1.5cm
        \oddsidemargin -.1cm
        \evensidemargin -.75cm


    %For references
    \renewcommand{\cite}[1]{[#1]}
    \def\beginrefs{\begin{list}%
    {[\arabic{equation}]}{\usecounter{equation}
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.0truecm}\setlength{\labelsep}{0.4truecm}%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.6truecm}}}
    \def\endrefs{\end{list}}
    \def\bibentry#1{\item[\hbox{[#1]}]}

     %      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
    \decimalpoint




\begin{document}

    \sloppy %para justificar correctamente las líneas
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}  
    \chapter{Quarks and color}
       \input{ch1quarkscolor}

      \chapter{Gauge invariance}
      \input{ch2gaugeinvariance}
        ...

      \end{document}
```

And this is the code around the section 5.3 Summary:

```
\section{Summary}

Lo importante es que realmente entendáis el concepto del o que estáis haciendo. En el capítulo de \hyperref[ch:renormalization]{Renormalización} cogimos un digrama de Feynman, la autoenergía, que tiene la estructura de Lorentz de la diapositiva 2.
```

Edit: I add the aux file when it gives the error:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\catcode `"\active 
\catcode `<\active 
\catcode `>\active 
\@nameuse{es@quoting}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\providecommand\tcolorbox@label[2]{}
\select@language{spanish}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Quarks and color}{1}{chapter.1}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Deep inelastic scattering: asymptotic freedom}{1}{section.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}Experimental data}{4}{subsection.1.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.2}Proton structure within QCD}{5}{subsection.1.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Number of colors}{6}{section.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}$\tau ^- \rightarrow \nu _\tau + \text  {hadrons}$}{6}{subsection.1.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Chiral anomaly}{7}{subsection.1.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Chiral gauge anomalies}{8}{subsection.1.2.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Why SU(3)?}{9}{section.1.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Gauge invariance}{11}{chapter.2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Quantum Electrodynamics (QED)}{11}{section.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.1}The Gauge Principle}{11}{subsection.2.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.2}QED Lagrangian}{12}{subsection.2.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD)}{14}{section.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.1}SU(N) gauge theories}{15}{subsection.2.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.2}QCD Lagrangian}{17}{subsection.2.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Infinitesimal SU(3) transformation}{18}{section*.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Kinetic term}{20}{section*.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.3}Detector LEP}{21}{subsection.2.2.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Symmetries and quantization}{22}{chapter.3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.1}Flavour symmetry}{22}{section.3.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.1}Chiral symmetry}{24}{subsection.3.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.2}Symmetry realizations}{26}{subsection.3.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.3}Goldstone Theorem}{28}{subsection.3.1.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Noether QCD currents}{31}{section*.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.2}Gauge fixing}{32}{section.3.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.1}Polarizations in QED}{35}{subsection.3.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.2}Polarizations in QCD. Ghosts.}{37}{subsection.3.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.3}QCD Lagrangian (II)}{39}{section.3.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.3.1}Feynman rules}{40}{subsection.3.3.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Propagators}{40}{section*.5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Vertices}{40}{section*.6}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Equations of motion}{40}{section*.7}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Useful information for exercise 3}{41}{section*.8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {4}Renormalization}{43}{chapter.4}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\newlabel{ch:renormalization}{{4}{43}{Renormalization}{chapter.4}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.1}Regularization}{44}{section.4.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.2}Dimensional regularization}{45}{section.4.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.2.1}Feynman parameters}{49}{subsection.4.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}Dimensional regularization with the Dirac algebra}{51}{section.4.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.4}Ultraviolet divergencies}{53}{section.4.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.1}Dimensional analysis}{57}{subsection.4.4.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.2}Energy scales in a scale-independent Lagrangian}{59}{subsection.4.4.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.3}Regularization schemes}{60}{subsection.4.4.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.4}Symmetry: CVC}{62}{subsection.4.4.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{The charge of the proton and the electron}{63}{section*.9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.5}Renormalization}{64}{section.4.5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.6}Summary}{68}{section.4.6}}
\newlabel{sec:summary}{{4.6}{68}{Summary}{section.4.6}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.7}Superficial degree of divergence}{72}{section.4.7}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{1-Particle Irreducible diagrams (1PI)}{75}{section*.10}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.8}QED UV divergencies}{75}{section.4.8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.9}Counterterms}{78}{section.4.9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.1}Photon self-energy}{81}{subsection.4.9.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.2}Fermion self-energy}{84}{subsection.4.9.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.3}Renormalization}{85}{subsection.4.9.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.4}MS scheme}{86}{subsection.4.9.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.10}Summary}{87}{section.4.10}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {5}Renormalization of QCD}{90}{chapter.5}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5.1}QCD UV divergencies}{90}{section.5.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.1}Quark self-energy}{92}{subsection.5.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.2}Gluon self-energy}{92}{subsection.5.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.3}Ghost self-energy}{94}{subsection.5.1.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.4}Ghost vertex}{94}{subsection.5.1.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.5}Fermionic vertex}{95}{subsection.5.1.5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.6}Triple gluon vertex}{95}{subsection.5.1.6}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.7}Quartic gluon vertex}{95}{subsection.5.1.7}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5.2}Renormalization}{95}{section.5.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5.3}Summar
```

And this is the aux file when I erase the aux file and I compile it from scratch without errors, in case it helps

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\catcode `"\active 
\catcode `<\active 
\catcode `>\active 
\@nameuse{es@quoting}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\providecommand\tcolorbox@label[2]{}
\select@language{spanish}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Quarks and color}{1}{chapter.1}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Deep inelastic scattering: asymptotic freedom}{1}{section.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}Experimental data}{4}{subsection.1.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.2}Proton structure within QCD}{5}{subsection.1.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Number of colors}{6}{section.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}$\tau ^- \rightarrow \nu _\tau + \text  {hadrons}$}{6}{subsection.1.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Chiral anomaly}{7}{subsection.1.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Chiral gauge anomalies}{8}{subsection.1.2.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Why SU(3)?}{9}{section.1.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Gauge invariance}{11}{chapter.2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Quantum Electrodynamics (QED)}{11}{section.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.1}The Gauge Principle}{11}{subsection.2.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.2}QED Lagrangian}{12}{subsection.2.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD)}{14}{section.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.1}SU(N) gauge theories}{15}{subsection.2.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.2}QCD Lagrangian}{17}{subsection.2.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Infinitesimal SU(3) transformation}{18}{section*.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Kinetic term}{20}{section*.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.3}Detector LEP}{21}{subsection.2.2.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Symmetries and quantization}{22}{chapter.3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.1}Flavour symmetry}{22}{section.3.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.1}Chiral symmetry}{24}{subsection.3.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.2}Symmetry realizations}{26}{subsection.3.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.3}Goldstone Theorem}{28}{subsection.3.1.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Noether QCD currents}{31}{section*.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.2}Gauge fixing}{32}{section.3.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.1}Polarizations in QED}{35}{subsection.3.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.2}Polarizations in QCD. Ghosts.}{37}{subsection.3.2.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.3}QCD Lagrangian (II)}{39}{section.3.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.3.1}Feynman rules}{40}{subsection.3.3.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Propagators}{40}{section*.5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Vertices}{40}{section*.6}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Equations of motion}{40}{section*.7}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Useful information for exercise 3}{41}{section*.8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {4}Renormalization}{43}{chapter.4}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\newlabel{ch:renormalization}{{4}{43}{Renormalization}{chapter.4}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.1}Regularization}{44}{section.4.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.2}Dimensional regularization}{45}{section.4.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.2.1}Feynman parameters}{49}{subsection.4.2.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}Dimensional regularization with the Dirac algebra}{51}{section.4.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.4}Ultraviolet divergencies}{53}{section.4.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.1}Dimensional analysis}{57}{subsection.4.4.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.2}Energy scales in a scale-independent Lagrangian}{59}{subsection.4.4.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.3}Regularization schemes}{60}{subsection.4.4.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4.4}Symmetry: CVC}{62}{subsection.4.4.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{The charge of the proton and the electron}{63}{section*.9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.5}Renormalization}{64}{section.4.5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.6}Summary}{68}{section.4.6}}
\newlabel{sec:summary}{{4.6}{68}{Summary}{section.4.6}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.7}Superficial degree of divergence}{72}{section.4.7}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{1-Particle Irreducible diagrams (1PI)}{75}{section*.10}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.8}QED UV divergencies}{75}{section.4.8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.9}Counterterms}{78}{section.4.9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.1}Photon self-energy}{81}{subsection.4.9.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.2}Fermion self-energy}{84}{subsection.4.9.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.3}Renormalization}{85}{subsection.4.9.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9.4}MS scheme}{86}{subsection.4.9.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.10}Summary}{87}{section.4.10}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {5}Renormalization of QCD}{90}{chapter.5}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5.1}QCD UV divergencies}{90}{section.5.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.1}Quark self-energy}{92}{subsection.5.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.2}Gluon self-energy}{92}{subsection.5.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.3}Ghost self-energy}{94}{subsection.5.1.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.4}Ghost vertex}{94}{subsection.5.1.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.5}Fermionic vertex}{95}{subsection.5.1.5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.6}Triple gluon vertex}{95}{subsection.5.1.6}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {5.1.7}Quartic gluon vertex}{95}{subsection.5.1.7}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5.2}Renormalization}{95}{section.5.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5.3}Summary}{97}{section.5.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {6}Renormalization group}{101}{chapter.6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6.1}Effective running coupling}{101}{section.6.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {6.1.1}QED running coupling}{102}{subsection.6.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {6.1.2}QCD running coupling: asymptotic freedom}{103}{subsection.6.1.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Why strong interacions are short-ranged?}{105}{section*.11}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {6.1.3}Resummation of Leading Logarithms in $\alpha (Q^2)$}{106}{subsection.6.1.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{2 Loops (NLO)}{107}{section*.12}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{$\alpha (Q^2)$ only invoves 1 input parameter}{109}{section*.13}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {6.1.4}Summary}{111}{subsection.6.1.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6.2}Running mass}{112}{section.6.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Runnning mass in QCD}{114}{section*.14}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6.3}Pole mass}{115}{section.6.3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Mass measurements in QCD}{116}{section*.15}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{Measurement of the top quark mass at Fermilab}{117}{section*.16}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6.4}QCD matching}{118}{section.6.4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6.5}Renormalization Group Equation}{119}{section.6.5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6.6}Summary}{120}{section.6.6}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {7}Inclusive processes}{125}{chapter.7}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {7.1}Jets at LEP}{126}{section.7.1}}
```

Comment: This is hardly answerable as long as you don't show the real code. If the error occurs at section 5.3 we need to have the code for the relevant chapter 5; `\input{ch1quarkscolor}` etc. are not really useful for us -- we have no idea what is inside of those files

Comment: unrelated, but the block of code starting `%For references` looks very odd, why are you completely disabling latex's citation mechanisms?

Comment: your aux file is corrupt but you have not enough information to guess why. The error is detected at the end of the aux file  so something written to the aux file has more `{` than `}`

Comment: The error seems to happen if a couple of chapters are there. I have tried to find out where the error is exactly in those two chapters, but it doesn't seem to be in any place in particular. If I erase the part of the code where it seems to be, it just pops up somewhere else.

I can write here the code of the two chapters, but it's quite long. I have seen that in the .aux file the headings of the sections are written. What do you recommend I focus in to find the error?

I have checked the number of { and } of my code, and there are the same number.

Comment: delete the aux file, then you will not get the error shown. then run latex, and gen an aux file, make sure you get no other errors, if the error comes back on a second run post the aux file here.

Comment: The references work nice in other documents I have. Anyway, since I'm not using them in this one, I commented them, so they should not be the problem. 
When I erase the aux file and I run it, it compiles OK, it just gives me some warnings related to using hyperref with math symbols. 
But if then I make an error, I run it, it tells me where the error is, I correct it and I run it again, the thing of the picture that I put on the post appears. I'll put the aux file here in case it helps